# I try to make components to be invisible when I clicked the button but it make my app stop right after I clicked the button

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to make components to be invisible but after I clicked a button. My app stop immediately
[I have an array like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KS9V.png)

[I try to make components to disappear like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qloai.png)

Comment: share you logcat and button listener code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is going out of bounds because your array has 6 elements in it and you're iterating from 0 to 6 (that's seven iterations)

Replace:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   findViewById(groupSong2[i]).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}
```

With this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   findViewById(groupSong2[i]).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}
```

Or even better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groupSong2.length; i++) {
   findViewById(groupSong2[i]).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}
```